# Bracha over searching kosher signs

Tags: blessing, mitzvah, animals, fish, birds

Is there a bracha that is made over searching the kosher signs of animals, whether animals, birds or fish - given that the Rambam lists these as individual mitzvot.

Comment: Can you provide a source please? (I am not doubting you, just curious.)

Comment: 145 To examine the marks in fishes (so as to distinguish the clean from the unclean (Lev. 11:9)

Comment: Rambam Sefer Hamitzvot, Positive Mitzvot 149-152.

Comment: There isn't. But many commandments don't have brachot associated with them